# What kind of sources can be put into Natron or other Compositors for Linux?

Tags: blender, compositing, synfig-studio

I read the article on Compositing on Wikipedia and few other random pages, yet I have still an open Question. I know for sure, that the kind of sources that can be put into any Compositor are pictures,sounds and movies , though I do not know which formats. But what about different sources, like for instance 3d models and 2d Vector graphics ?

*Is it possible to build a simple 3d model in Blender and use it as a source in Natron ? 
* Is it possible to use a project from Synfig within Natron ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file formats supported will depend on the software you choose to use.

From the Natron website -

> Dozens of file formats supported: EXR, DPX,TIFF, JPG, PNG…thanks to OpenImageIO and FFmpeg.

And from the OpenImageIO readme -

> Plugins implementing I/O for several popular image file formats, including TIFF, JPEG/JFIF, OpenEXR, PNG, HDR/RGBE, ICO, BMP, Targa, JPEG-2000, RMan Zfile, FITS, DDS, Softimage PIC, PNM, DPX, Cineon, IFF, Field3D, Ptex, Photoshop PSD, Wavefront RLA, SGI, WebP, GIF, and a variety of "RAW" digital camera formats, and a variety of movie formats (readable as individual frames).

You will find a similar list of formats in ffmpeg's documentation.

Natron composites bitmap images and I don't see mention of vector based images in the list, but you can open a vector image file in synfig or inkscape and save a bitmap copy of the image to fit the compositing project. For animations synfig saves an image sequence if you choose a single image format.

You will need to do similar steps for 3d objects, render out the object to an image that you can then read with natron. Using an image that supports alpha channels, like png, will make the task easier.